# What is the difference between test method and test tag inTestng

Tags: testng

I'm using TestNG for some time now but still I don't know what's the intended purpose of those two (`@Test` and `< test>` in suite.xml)and what abstractions they are meant to express.

Also if anyone can share the difference in their behavior regarding other elements in TestNG. For example are `@AfterTest` `@BeforeTest` triggered by `@Test` or `<test>` and which one of `@Test` and `< test>` gets into the final execution report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@Test` denotes a test method. `<test>` is a how you group several classes together in your `testng.xml`.

Comment: is it possible to execute only classes under specific <test> tag ?. Any idea for this issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47436748/how-to-run-a-single-classes-under-single-test-tag-in-testng-suite

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Cedric's answer, on your second question

@AfterTest runs after  in the xml

@AfterMethod runs after @Test in your java file.

eg.

```
public class TestCases{
@Test
public void test1()..
@Test
public void test2()..
}

public class MoreTestCases{
@Test
public void test1()..
@Test
public void test2()..
}
```

So you have 4 testcases annotated with @Test

Now, for  in the xml is how you want to structure your running of tests

```
 <test>
   <classes>
    <class name = TestCases>
      <methods>
        <include name = test1/>
      </methods>
    </class>
   <class name = TestCases>
     <methods>
       <include name = test1/>
     </methods>
   </class>
  </classes>
</test>
```

So your  now is run only test1 from both your classes.

The terminology is a bit confusing at the start...but I hope it helps clear things a bit.

Comment: Thank you. I was expecting something like this kind of answer. Helped me understand better the idea and structuring.