# Will inherited @BeforeTest Method run multiple times?

Tags: selenium, testng, testng-annotation-test

When using TestNG, If multiple test classes inherit a class containing a @BeforeTest method, will it run only once or everytime when each of the classes are called in the test case?

When I run the below code, the text "BEFORE TEST EXECUTED" is printed only once. Though both the test classes have this method inherited.

```
public class masterclass
{

@BeforeTest
public void show()
 {
 sout("BEFORE TEST EXECUTED")
 }
}
```

Test Class-1:

```
public class TestClass1 extends masterclass
 {
    @Test
    public void testA1() { }
}
```

Test Class-2:

```
public class TestClass2 extends masterclass
{
    @Test
    public void testB1() {}    
}
```

XML of the test Case :

```
<suite  name="testSuite">
<test name="MytestCase" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ui.test.TestClass1" />
        <class name="com.ui.test.TestClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Comment: I can't understand question. Can you please provide sample code? Please check it too https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120219/how-do-you-ask-a-question-on-stack-overflow

Comment: I have added sample code. Since the BeforeTest method is inherited by both classes in the test case, and TestNG will execute all BeforeTests in all the classes inside a test case at the beginning of execution of that test case, it should execute the BeforeTest two times right?

Comment: What is exactly your issue? You are asking your doubt or it is a problem/issue ? Do you want to call @BeforeTest method before every test case? I just give the logical reason why Before test call will be one time. if you want solution let me know?

Comment: I am wondering why my @BeforeTest is executed only once in this case. Because since i am having two classes in the test case. And both these classes have this BeforeTest method (Beacuse of inheritance), there should be 2 BeforeTest Executions in total in the beginning of the test case right? But why is this executed only once in this case?

Comment: That I have mentioned in answer why it is one time. It is because of annotation @BeforeTest which will execute one time before  all test class/Test case in <test> tag in testng.xml. Hope you understand it.

Comment: So you are saying only one BeforeTest method execution will happen for each test case? If there are many beforetest methods all the rest will be ignored?!

Comment: when I say "one BeforeTest method execution will happen for each test case"? I mentioned "annotation BeforeTest which will execute one time before all test class/Test case in <test> tag in testng.xml".  Please check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218863/what-is-the-difference-between-test-method-and-test-tag-intestng, I think you are confused between @Test and <test> tag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204408/discussion-between-automaticsoldier-and-muzzamil).

Answer (score 3):

In your case, `@BeforeTest` will run one time. It will see to `Testng.xml` and will run before all test cases under `<test>` tag.

**Master Test Class:**

```
public class MasterClass {
    @BeforeTest
    public void show()
     {
     System.out.println("BEFORE TEST EXECUTED");
     }

}
```

**Test Class-1:**

```
public class TestClass1 extends MasterClass{

      @Test
       public void test()
          {
          System.out.println("Priority 0 (Default in Class 1)");
          }
   }
```

**Test Class-2:**

```
public class TestClass2 extends MasterClass{


      @Test(priority = 0)
       public void testin_LearningTestNGTest2_Class()
          {
          System.out.println("Priority 0 (Class 2)");
          }
   }
```

**TestNG.xml:**

```
<suite  name="testSuite">
<test name="MytestCase">
    <classes>
        <class name="com.ui.test.TestClass1" />
        <class name="com.ui.test.TestClass2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

**Output:**

```
BEFORE TEST EXECUTED
Priority 0 (Default in Class 1)
Priority 0 (Class 2)
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Please accept it as answer if it solved your problem. It will be helpful for people have same issue in future. Thanks

Comment: I am wondering why my @BeforeTest is executed only once in this case. Because since i am having two classes in the test case. And both these classes have this BeforeTest method (Beacuse of inheritance), there should be 2 BeforeTest Executions in total in the beginning of the test case right? But why is this executed only once in this case?

Comment: if you will change BeforeTest to @BeforeMethod in MasterClass then it will serve your purpose.